# S3 Bucket File Prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, matillion

I have filenames in S3 buckets are like

abc_Assessment_20210302.csv
xyz_Assessment_20210302.csv
mno_Assessment_20210302.csv

where keyword is Assessment.

As a variable I am passing * Assessment * to find the all assessment related files into S3 bucket to get processed into Staging table.

but s3_file_file_prefix as * Assessment * is not working here and unable to list those assement related files here in matillion jobs.

Need help.

Comment: what is your target DB in Matillion?  If Snowflake, you use the pattern property: `*Assessment.*`  (the trailing wildcard is .*   not *)

Comment: If your target DB is Redshift, you use a manifest file with Regex pattern matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In S3, * can't be used to consider any character.
Assuming that you are passing * Assessment * as value for prefix parameter, that is exactly what it'll look for. Files with keys as "* Assessment *{remaining_file_name}.

You might try the [delimiter parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html#API_ListObjects_RequestSyntax) in the request